# What is an efficient way to search a table for specified column values in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is used for "searching" a table.
I want an exact match for the fields that are specified.

I would like to know what ways I can efficiently implement this functionality!

Here is an example of my initial attempt. I created a compound `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_TableA_Search
    @ColumnA int = null,
    @ColumnB uniqueidentifier = null
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM TableA
    WHERE
        (@ColumnA IS NULL OR @ColumnA = ColumnA)
        AND
        (@ColumnB IS NULL OR @ColumnB = ColumnB)
```

This method feels very inefficient to me. I'm not sure if SQL will repeatedly check `@ColumnA` and `@ColumnB` for `NULL`? And I've heard that SQL will create an execution plan, that might not work as well when there's variable paths like this.

**Is there a better way to construct this sproc?**

Also, what resources can I use to determine the efficiency of my SQL code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this is done pretty well with Dynamic SQL, as long as you do it right.

SQLDenis wrote a good [blog post](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/do-you-use-column-param-or-param-is-null) about this.

Comment: This article also mentions another article that I found useful: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/